# go tool: no such tool "compile"

Tags: go, goclipse

I recently started trying go to program some web based applications. At first, everything went fine, until I wanted to cross compile a binary for a different platform. I'm running MacOS and I wanted to compile a binary for linux, so I changed `GOOS` to `linux` and `GOARCH` to `amd64`. Since then, I always get the error message

```
go tool: no such tool "compile"
```

I'm using GoClipse, but running the compile manually by

```
go install hello.go
```

I get the same error. When changing back to compiling for darwin architecture, I get the same error now, so basically I'm totally unable to compile any code written in Go at the moment.

Comment: How did you install Go (source? installer? Homebrew) and did you install the cross-compilers as well? As per @OneofOne's answer, if you have cgo dependencies then cross-compiling becomes complicated (oft. easier to just spin up a small Vagrant box).

Comment: cross compiling  try [gox](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox) ?

Comment: Here is the line printing this error : https://github.com/golang/go/blob/21ec72c2ca5168f3f10b4594a553b3a038c8df29/src/cmd/go/tool.go#L61

Comment: Can you give the full output of `go env` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed it via the binary packages provided by google. In the end I actually got it back to work by just reinstalling it. Sometimes I'm just blind to the easy solution.

After that, I succeeded in cross compiling for linux machine after compiling the necessary cross-compilers by running `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go ./make.bash --no-clean` from the Go sources directory.

Thanks for all you efforts, sorry to have kept you busy on such a simple matter.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong x64 or x386 package installed most likely. I had 32 installed running 64 bit. Reinstall fixed. Good luck.

Comment: I got same error, as my x64 PC runs the 'go build' with the x32/386 go package

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with that if you install Go 1.5, however if you use anything that depends on `cgo`, you will have to install a cross-compiler linker or install Linux on a virtual machine to be able to cross compile for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In my case is due to the fact that GOPATH and GOROOT are not set correctly, maybe you can check `go env`. [Here is a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/iTCTqG_JcW0) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured-out what file is read and caused Go to look for the compile binary in the wrong place can be solved using:
$ strace go tool -n compile 2>&1 |grep openat

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/nwaizer/.config/go/env", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

In that file, the IDE Goland, add a path to some project, causing the havoc.